# Formatting is Specified but argument is not IFormattable

Tags: c#

```
string listOfItemPrices = items.ToSemiColonList(item => string.Format("{0:C}", item.Price.ToString()));
```

I am simply trying to format the price here to 2 decimal places.  Ok, so the string.Format doesn't implement IFormattable?  Ok not sure how to get around this so that I can format the decimal (price) here.

Answer (score 19):

By passing `item.Price.ToString()` to `String.Format`, you are passing a *string*, not a decimal.
Since strings cannot be used with format strings, you're getting an error.

You need to pass the *`Decimal`* value to `String.Format` by removing `.ToString()`.

Comment: I'm getting the same with:
inFile.setINVQueryDept( string.Format("{0:#0.00}", frmCentral.startDept), string.Format("{0:#0.00}", frmCentral.endDept));

Answer (score 2):

There is no point using string.format here, that is used for adding formatted values into strings. e.g.

```
String.Format("This is my first formatted string {O:C} and this is my second {0:C}",ADecimal,AnotherDecimal)
```

If you just want the value of a decimal variable as a formatted string then just pass the string formatter to the ToString() method e.g.

```
ADecimal.ToString("C");
```